# Using Xcode4 git integration with git-flow

Tags: git, xcode4, git-flow

Just wondering if anyone is using Xcode4's git integration to work with a project using git-flow?  If so, did you have to do anything in particular to get it set up and working?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've discovered that Xcode does not play well with Git Flow.  I've decided to just do all my repo stuff through the terminal.

Comment: Xcode doesn't really play well with git at all. They deliberately decided to support the lowest common denominator of the featuresets of git and SVN. So, no branching, no stashes, no staging... It's pretty stupid.

Comment: Xcode 5 does now have a fairly simple but effective set of git tools. But for setting up Git Flow and for more detailed work, I use SourceTree.

Answer (score 2):

I know it is too late for answer, but finally I created a gitflow plugin for Xcode: https://github.com/alexkrzyzanowski/xcode-gitflow-plugin

The plugin is also available via Alcatraz.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/). I'm new to git and git flow, coming from a long time svn background, it really made all the difference in the world, trying to understand what was on my machine and what was on the remote, commercially hosted, server.

Xcode lets me know if something is modifed etc... but that is only a visual aid, that's all.